# $_POST is empty when obtaining in "ErrorDocument 404" (nginx + apache + mod_php)

Tags: nginx, php, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-php

I try to transfer website from old server to new, and stucked with one problem. PHP/JS code on both servers is the same, but on new server it is not working - $_POST data are empty in AJAX-request.

**Some details:**

**Old server**: Debian 7, Nginx + Apache(mod_php 7.4)

**New server**: Ubuntu 22.04, Nginx 1.18.0 + Apache 2.4.52 (mod_php 7.4)

Requested address /basket/add/. It isn't exist, .htaccess contains rule
`ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

404.php contains router for logical url's, which should read $_POST and add product to basket.
I add `var_dump($_POST);` at the very beginning of 404.php, but $_POST always empty array().

When the same request is going to existing file (not to 404.php), $_POST are filled normally.

So, the problem is in .htaccess directive `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`. Old server see $_POST in 404.php correctly, but new server - no.

I really can't understand, why it happens. Any ideas?

Comment: How does Nginx fit into this scenario? Using `ErrorDocument` in that way is a bit "hacky" and means you need to explicitly override the HTTP status on every request. Why are you doing it that way and not using mod_dir `FallbackResource` or explicitly rewriting the request using mod_rewrite?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the request that reaches your `/404.php` file is still a POST request or is it being _converted_ to GET (hence why the POST data is lost)?

Comment: Nginx is proxy (give static files and proxying php to apache). POST definetely not converted to GET. I also var_dump $_REQUEST and $_GET, they are empty too. So, request data is lost completely.

Comment: remember that you need to install and activate any modules on the new apache server...  this is a common problem and issue that people forget about to solve